# javascript get EVERY possible combination of a string

Tags: javascript, string, combinations

I have searched an hour+ for this, and cannot find one that works. I need a function that generates every combination of a string, with a certain amount of characters.

For example, if I passed in "abc" and 2, it would return

["ab", "ac",

"ba", "bc",

"ca", "cb"]

as an array of strings.
Thank you for any help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: Show what you've done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getCombinations('abc',2);

function getCombinations(string,length){

    var combinations = [];
    function findCombinations(token,string){
        if(token.length >= length){     
            combinations.push(token);
        }else{
            for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){
                findCombinations(token + string.charAt(i),string.slice(0, i) + string.slice(i+1));
            }   
        }   

        return combinations;
    }

    return findCombinations('',string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! I really appreciate it